# Strategies for Debugging Column Name Resolution Issue in Hive on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a program in spark that executes several HiveQL strings in succession, mainly doing something like

```
DataFrame df = HiveContext.sql("HQL Statement");
df.registerTempTable("df");
DataFrame df2 = HiveContext.sql("HQL Statement Referencing df");
```

While I have no trouble doing this in simple cases, I'm running into issues when trying to do this with several complex queries in succession, often referencing temp tables I've created several times over.

Mainly my errors are column name resolution errors, something like:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
resolved attribute(s) people#5323L,grp#5322 missing from 
age#20,secondary_email#17,email#6,last_login#16, ..., 
grp#5322, people#5323L
```

Which I find odd anyway since the desired columns are in the attribute list, but nevertheless, this problem is usually easily solved by using a `select people as people` line in some part of the HQL statement so that the column name resolves correctly.

The problem is that I often seem to have multiple name resolution errors and fixing some errors creates others. I'm driving myself mad.

Does anyone have any debugging strategies that help them with this issue? Or better yet a strategy for writing HQL that does not generate this error? I'm really at a loss for how to debug this effectively and searching the internet/trial and error has not proven fruitful.

Comment: +1. I m running into the same problem also, and it will be really helpful to get such mechanism of debugging.